# How to get data from sql database in an angular 2 app?

Tags: database, angular

I have designed a database which I want to connect to an angular 2 app that I am building. I want to know how to get or update data from a sql database into my application .

Answer (score 5):

Angular 2, being a client-side framework, does not care *how* you get data from your SQL database into the app. This data retrieval will be the job of your server. While you have many options for a server, [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) is fairly popular.
You would then use Angular 2 [services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) to move data between your Angular 2 client-side app and your server.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a option, NOT taking in consideration if this is a smart way or not... just an option:

You could use PHP if e.g working with MySQL. More info here [Integrating Angular 2 with PHP](http://4dev.tech/2016/07/using-http-client-to-integrate-angular2-to-php/)

Example to retrieve data from table:

PHP:

```
<?php
    // more code here...
    $query = "SELECT something FROM table";
    // more code... e.g perform query...
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Angular 2 service:

```
getData(){
    return this.http.get('pathToPHPscript')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}
```